# Android Studio :Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I'm new to Android Studio and I have another problem.
I'm risking my last reputation point btw.

So I'm following the steps from this website: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html
More precisely at the section: Use Platform Styles and Themes

I don't understand my mistake and why does it show me an error.
Also, what does this error mean?

So here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bog.beg">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<!-- SET THE VERSIONS -->

    <application


        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"></activity>

        <!-- ACTIVITY SETS -->
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />


    </application>



</manifest>
```

If I add the `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />`,
 it gives me this error

```
`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`
```

I saw my logs. I'm not sure if this is it:

```
    -- Merging decision tree log ---
manifest
ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:2:1-33:12
    package
        ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:3:5-34
        INJECTED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
        INJECTED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
    android:versionName
        INJECTED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
        INJECTED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
    xmlns:android
        ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:2:11-69
    android:versionCode
        INJECTED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
        INJECTED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
uses-sdk
ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-73
MERGED from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-23:78
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-23:54
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-fragment:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-fragment\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-23:60
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-media-compat\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-23:63
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-core-ui\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-23:58
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-core-utils\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-23:61
MERGED from [com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-44
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-vector-drawable\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-43
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-compat\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-23:58
    tools:overrideLibrary
        ADDED from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-75
    android:targetSdkVersion
        ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:5:41-70
        INJECTED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
        INJECTED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
    android:minSdkVersion
        ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:5:15-40
        INJECTED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
        INJECTED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
application
ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-29:19
MERGED from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-20
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-20
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-fragment:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-fragment\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-20
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-media-compat\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-20
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-core-ui\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-20
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-core-utils\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-20
MERGED from [com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-20
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-vector-drawable\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:23:5-20
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.0] C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-compat\25.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-20
    android:label
        ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-41
    android:supportsRtl
        ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-35
    android:allowBackup
        ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:11:9-35
    android:icon
        ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-43
    android:theme
        ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-40
activity#com.example.bog.beg.MainActivity
ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-22:20
    android:name
        ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:16:19-47
intent-filter#android.intent.action.MAIN+android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:17:13-21:29
action#android.intent.action.MAIN
ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:18:17-69
    android:name
        ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:18:25-66
category#android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:20:17-77
    android:name
        ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:20:27-74
activity#com.example.bog.beg.DisplayMessageActivity
ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-69
    android:name
        ADDED from C:\Users\bog\AndroidStudioProjects\Beg\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:23:19-57
```

If I remove the `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />`, 
there is no error showing, but why does this happen?

I don't know if the style needs to be created by myself or if it is given by default (which makes more sense to me).

Answer (score 0):

> what does this error mean.

`:app:processDebugManifest'`. > `Manifest merger failed`

Quite simply, there is an error in the  `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

---

From the documentation...

> The name must be specified.

[Android - `<activity>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

I do not see an `android:name` in

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

---

Basically, I think all that the link that you provided was trying to show was you can specify there exists an `android:theme` attribute that can either be applied to an `<activity>` or to `<application>`.

For example,

```
<activity 
    android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Or what you already have

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand.

Comment: Sorry, pressed Enter too soon. Anyway::: The <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />  is not a necessity, but if I want to have it, I need a name. I've now set an android:name="stuff",  which means I need to use this activity (If I'm not wrong ) somewhere in my application. If I'm once again correct, I need to use it in style. Is that it??

Comment: FORGET IT ALL. As you mentioned, I already had a android:theme...  I just set "@android:style.Thee.Translucent". Is this going to affect my project in a bad way??

Comment: Because I changed it, but now is giving me an error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: 1) `FATAL EXCEPTION: main` is from a Java error, and you have no code in your question, so I cannot answer that. 2) Yes `android:name` is necessary 3) No, `android:theme` is not needed on any activity unless you want to override the one within `<application>`. I don't know what you mean by "bad way" because you seem to have other errors within your code.